# Custom rewrites for pages and categories

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules

I am trying to understand how can create custom rewrites for pages/categories. Ex i have `example.com/?page_id=178` and for this page have a contact form and i want this: `%slug%.php`

```
example.com/contact.php
```

In the permalinks i have two choices.
1) Is the **Post name** and the 2) is the **Custom Structure** : %postname%/ . With both cases i didn't have the result that i want. It is possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have `domain.tld/PAGE-NAME.php` then you could just use `%postname%.php` as custom structure.

**// Edit**

As this approach seems to work for posts only, you might have a try with the structure `/%postname%/`. In addition, you put the following lines to your .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*).php /$1/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

**// Edit**, again

Replacing in the plugin file of [.html on PAGES](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/html-on-pages/) each occurrence of "html" with "php" AND having set permalinks to `/%postname%.php` should do the trick. I have **not** checked the plugin for deprecated functions and the like - it works, though.

Comment: Dam, in the live site i receive a **404 - Not Found** with or without `/%postname%` or `/%postname%.php`. When i am in the localhost works only the `/%postname%` , for the case of `/%postname%/.php` don't work.

Comment: I just tested my suggestion, and you're right. This works for POSTS only (not for pages). You could use the structure `/%postname%/` and add a RewriteRule to your .htaccess (see my edit above).

Comment: It is not possible to do that. My host provider didn't support `.htaccess`

Comment: I just found this (old) plugin: [.html on PAGES](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/html-on-pages/) and tested it. In the php file, you just have to replace each occurrence of 'html' with 'php', AND set your permalinks to `/%postname%.php`. This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the share. This plugin Requires: 2.5.1 or higher, and i have the 3.4. If i have installed and then uninstall It will affect the permalinks? I don't want to use with posts. Only for pages/categories.

Comment: By default, yes it will also affect posts, because you set the permalinks that way. If you want to treat posts and pages differently, you have to delete the two occurrences of the line `if ( !strpos($wp_rewrite->get_page_permastruct(), '.php')){` in the plugin file (as well as the two according closing curly brackets `}`).

Comment: Probably i have to delete this :  `if ( !strpos($wp_rewrite->get_page_permastruct(), '.html')){
  $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->page_structure . '.html';
 } `
} and  `if ($wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() && $wp_rewrite->use_trailing_slashes==true && $type == 'page'){
  return untrailingslashit($string);
  }else{
   return $string;
  } ` (with else)

Comment: didn't work. The message that i have is **404 - Not Found**

Comment: Are you working localhost, or can you give me a link to your website?

Comment: localhost and live. Sorry, but i cannot give the url of live site. I read that the **404 - Not Found** is the problem with .htaccess file, but my host provider didn't support this.

Comment: I communicate with my host provider and activated the rewrites. After that I don't have any errors like **404-Not found**. I didn't have the result that i want like contact.php, but i will settle. If anyone have any other solution, I will be happy to read it.

Comment: If you use [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/89402/27722), you do NOT get the desired result? That is exactly what I tested - and that worked the way you described. I get `domain.tld/my-post-name/` for posts and `domain.tld/my-page-name.php` for pages.

Comment: yes it works. But if i want to display for categories and posts, how can do that?

Comment: If you want to establish a hierarrchy like 'category -> post' then just use `/%category%/%postname%` as permalink structure.

Comment: Custom Structure :  `/%category%/%postname%.php ` and didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want to have in the plugin file:

```
add_action('init', 'php_page_permalink', -1);
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'active');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'deactive');


function php_page_permalink() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->get_page_permastruct();
    $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->page_structure . '.php';
}

add_filter('user_trailingslashit', 'no_page_slash',66,2);
function no_page_slash($string, $type){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    if ($wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() && $wp_rewrite->use_trailing_slashes==true && $type == 'page'){
        return untrailingslashit($string);
    }else{
        return $string;
    }
}

function active() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->get_page_permastruct();
        $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->page_structure . '.php';
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

function deactive() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->get_page_permastruct();
    $wp_rewrite->page_structure = str_replace(".php","",$wp_rewrite->page_structure);
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

**// Edit**

I forgot to mention that with this code, you can leave your permalink settings the way you want (e.g. like `/%postname%/` if you want your posts to be formatted that way).

Comment: And? Is it working for you as well? If not, what's the problem? What is working and what is not?